# Slider is not rendered properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want to do simple slider based on margin-left css property, but it looks that the result is not rendered between partial margin-left increments. What is wrong with my code?

https://jsfiddle.net/1utkr6et/

**html:**

```
<div class="main-padding">
    <div id="wrapper-slider">
        <div class="item-slider item-slider1"></div>
        <div class="item-slider item-slider2"></div>
        <div class="item-slider item-slider3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
* {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

ul, ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.main-padding {
    padding: 20px;
}


#wrapper-slider {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item-slider {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.item-slider1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.item-slider2 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.item-slider3 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**js(jquery):**

```
$(function () {

    var item = ".item-slider";
    var next = 1;
    setInterval(function() {
        $(item + next).animate({"marginLeft": "-100%"}, 1000);
        next++;
    }, 2000);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your slider is that you are defining the elements of slider `float`. I have made a few changes in your code to make this work properly.

**CSS:**

```
.item-slider {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {

    var item = ".item-slider";
    var next = 1;
    var current;
    setInterval(function() {
        if(next === 1){
            prev = $(item + 3);
        }else{
            prev = $(item + (next - 1));
        }
        current = $(item + next);
        current.css({"left": "100%"});
        current.animate({"left": "0"}, 1000);
        prev.animate({"left": "-100%"}, 1000);
        if(next === 3){
            next = 1;
        }else{
            next++;
        }
    }, 2000);

});
```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/1utkr6et/5/

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a width for wrapper-slider eg  `width:300%;` 100% for each slide. However the `padding` for `main-padding` makes it dificult for the slides as they are next to each other so you can see about 20px of the next slide. Unless there is a better way i suggest not using the padding as i have in the Demo.

You also need to calculate each slides width too.

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/twgvxj1z/

**Code**

```
var tt = $(window).width();
$(".item-slider").css("width", tt+"px");
```